# Redirect /index.php to /folder/index.php without showing a 301 redirect or change in url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We have a multi-domain webstore with a single database running on a virtual host which uses the following .htaccess to separate the domains for different languages.

Operationally it works fine but it shows up each redirected file as a 301 redirect, as it of course should.

1) Is it possible to have the redirect without showing a 301 redirect (instead showing a 200)?

2) Is it possible to have the index.php redirect without showing a 301 redirect (instead showing a 200) or change in url?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect all files except robots.txt to Store subfolder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^robots\.txt$ /folder1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^robots\.txt$ /folder2/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain3\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^robots\.txt$ /folder3/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have the redirect without showing a 301 redirect (instead showing a 200)?

This is called a rewrite, not a redirect. A redirect is a response sent to the browser to load a *different* URL, and when it does this, it'll show in the location bar what it loaded. A rewrite stays entirely on the server's end and the browser knows nothing about it, so the location bar doesn't change because it's never been told to load a new URL.

> Is it possible to have the index.php redirect without showing a 301 redirect (instead showing a 200) or change in url?

You want something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder1/$1 [L]
```

etc.

Notice that there is no `R=301` flag, which tells mod_rewrite to redirect the browser.

Comment: That didn't quite do what we want.

After further thought we need all, except index.php, [domain1.com] urls to redirect to [domain1.com/folder1/] with the correct URL shown. HTTP/1.1 200

Whereas index.php should redirect to [domain1.com/folder1/index.php] with [domain1.com/index.php] URL shown. HTTP/1.1 200